# How to delete a specific folder using a full path string?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am uploading some attachments to server and saving the path in database. I was required to save the full path of the file in database, not only the filename. Now I need to delete a specific folder if user upload another attachments. This is how the path looks in database.

> C:\Users\User\Desktop\Jobsheet\JobsheetAd\JobData\JobAttachments\180118\18018441\productpreview.jpeg

I need to delete the folder 18018441 if user uploads new attachments.

```
if (path != "")
{
   Directory.Delete(path, true);
}
```

I am not sure how to delete the specific folder. Please guide me.

Comment: Which is the specific folder you have to delete?

Comment: he has mentioned the folder in the line between the quote and code

Comment: Sorry, missed that.

Comment: what do you know about the folder structure? are you sure the folder name won't repeat twice in the path? are you sure about the first past of the path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Path.GetDirectoryName()`

```
string filePath = @"C:\Users\User\Desktop\Jobsheet\JobsheetAd\JobData\JobAttachments\180118\18018441\productpreview.jpeg";
string fullFolderPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath);
// your other logic here
if (Directory.Exists(fullFolderPath)
{
   Directory.Delete(fullFolderPath, true);
}
```

Comment: @NevilleNazerane yes, correct. It just needs to supply the second parameter.

Comment: thank you, this is what i wanted

Answer (score 1):

Use this method to get the directory path from the file path:

```
Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath);
```